# Fetching 500K+ of rows from Oracle DB using Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am fetching rows from a table for writing the rows to csv file, but this table contains more than 500,000 rows, so while fetching data it throws "**heap out of memory**" exception. How to handle this?

Comment: paste your code, so that we know what (and how) are you doing?

Comment: With plain JDBC I do a paged query (i.e. using LIMIT clause on MySQL or ROWNUM on Oracle) so you should look for the corresponding facility in Hibernate.

Comment: but i am using hibernate.

Comment: HcFilter hcFilter = new HcFilter(filterSettings, getEntityClass(), getIdField());
                list = getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(hcFilter);

Comment: I have give the code above which I am using

Comment: Here Through filtersetting I am just setting firstresult and Maxresult  of the query and right now i set both the value 0 as i have to fetch all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`query.scroll()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#scroll%28%29) insteand of `query.list()` to get the results of your query. This will avoid loading the whole result set into memory.

Comment: I am using the code given belowSo how to use here.              HcFilter hcFilter = new HcFilter(filterSettings, getEntityClass(), getIdField());
                list = getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(hcFilter);

Comment: HibernateTemplate, which shouldn't be used anymore as documented, calls `query.list()` behind the scenes. Use `HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateCallback)`, and inside the callback, execute a query using `query.scroll()`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - this will allow me to use producer-consumer design pattern when using JPA?

Answer (score 1):

You could try paginating your query to fetch and process your data in batches:

```
// Would 1000 records per batch be optimal?
final int pageSize = 1000;
int pageNumber = 1;
boolean done = false;

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class);
while (! done) {
    criteria.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
    criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);

    List<MyEntity> ents = (List<MyEntity>) criteria.list();
    if (ents != null) {
        for (MyEntity e : ents) {
            // Process the entity.
        }
        // Maybe check for ending like this?
        // done = ents.size() < pageSize;
        pageNumber++;
    }
    else {
        // No more data.
        done = true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

[This article](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/52846-pagination-in-big-result-sets-oracle-hibernate) is back from 2008, but it discusses your issue. Someone there said the slow speed comes from the Oracle server. They also discuss about `query.scroll()`.

You should check [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpql-pagination-oracle) and these two from Oracle: [top-N queries](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html) and [ROWNUM limiting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html).

**UPDATE**

Just found this [article on processing huge files](http://deephacks.org/2013/01/13/huge-files.html). It's not intended for database processing but it might be useful in the future.

Comment: I tried the concept of the pagination but it slow down the performance because it takes long time .

Comment: yes i got the solution I dont need to do any thing just i increased the jvm memory on start up.

Comment: Good one :-) You should consider some kind of stream / batch processing approach for this kind of problem. You might not be able / allowed to increase memory on some environments.